# Galois field splitting a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, galois-theory, splitting-field

Can someone explain to me how i would go about doing a problem like this? I don't really know where to start. GF refers to a Galois field. I'm struggling to even understand exactly what they want me to do here.

[image]

Comment: $GF(q)$, where $q$ is a prime power, refers to the finite field with $q$ elements.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just not sure what to do with that. I assume the prime power will be that of 2^n because of the field

Answer (score 2):

The point here to realize is that all fields of size $p^n$ are isomorphic and that you construct a (and hence the) field of $p^n$ elements by taking ${\mathbb F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ for some irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in {\mathbb F}_p[x]$ of degree $n$.

Comment: any way that you could explain this more or even give me an example of contructing that? I'm really having trouble with the notation.

Comment: What is troubling? You need to give me some idea of your background. For instance, how would you construct a field of $p^n$ elements?

Comment: the way i see it, their is no integer q such that q will be a root for the polynomial in mod 2. thats why i don't get it. I can split polynomial fields with complex numbers, just not integers.

Comment: If you mean, there is no $q \in {\mathbb F}_2$ (i.e., $q = 0$ or $q = 1$) such that that polynomial has $q$ as root: that is correct, but does not (yet) show that the polynomial is irreducible. It might factor as a product of two quadratic polynomials. (It doesn't, but it something you have to argue). If you mean something else (for instance, if the $q$ you mention in the comment has anything to do with the $q$ from the question), then I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: What do i do after showing it is irreducible?

Comment: Well, then you know ${\mathbb F}_2[x]/(x^4 + x^3 + 1) \cong {\mathbb F}_{16}$.

Comment: So then a field of size 16 is the splitting field, and since all fields size 16 are isomorphic, GF(16) is the splitting field?

Comment: Yes, but there are still some technicalities you might want to understand. For someone who is familiar enough with this subject, the argument "$x^4 + x^3 + 1$ is irreducible over ${\mathbb F}_2$, therefore its splitting field is ${\mathbb F}_{2^4}$" is ok.

Comment: thank you for all your help!